# Add months in date/time Parameter value in ssrs

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

I have FromDate & ToDate as parameters in my report.
If user enters nothing, then fromdate will be = current date - 4 months.
& if user enters something in FromDate then fromdate will be = FromDate - 4 months.

I have tried below expression but unluckly it doesn't work.

=iif(ISNOTHING(Parameters!FromDate.Value),
format(Today.AddDays(1- Today.Day).AddMonths(-4),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -4, Parameters!FromDate.Value),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend making the Parameter to be nullable.  Then in your stored procedure make the parameter nullable.  Then in the actual procedure set the data parameter to the value you want.

```
Alter Procedure rpt_GetDateInfo
(
@ToDate DATETIME,
@FromDate DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

IF ( @FromDate IS NULL )
BEGIN

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(m,4,@ToDate)

END

PRINT @FromDate

END
```

This is just an example of allowing a null parameter in the procedure and then setting it.  This should be easier than trying to do it in the RDL.

Comment: Please re-read my question. Its for Parameter value in SSRS & not in SQL.